# Convert a SharePoint Online list into JSON using arrays

Tags: arrays, json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to convert a set of SharePoint list items (and associated data) into a JSON object. To do this I'm trying to create a multi-dimensional array and then iterate over my SharePoint objects to populate it.

This is the relevant code so far:

```
#Lookup Source Address 
$rootWeb = $Context.Web
$List = $rootWeb.lists.getByTitle($ListName)
$fields = $List.Fields;
$ListItems = $List.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())

#Load the List
$Context.Load($rootWeb)
$Context.Load($List)
$Context.Load($ListItems)
$context.Load($fields)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

$listArray = @()
$listArray["DisplayTitle"] = @()
$listArray["Description"] = @()
$listArray["Setting"] = @()
$listArray["HealthAreas"] = @()
$listArray["ResourceType"] = @()
$listArray["ExternalURL"] = @()
$listArray["Active"] = @()

Write-Host "List items are"
foreach ($item in $ListItems)
{
    $listArray["DisplayTitle"].Add($item["Title"])
    $listArray["Description"].Add($item["File Description"])
    $listArray["Setting"].Add($item["Setting"])
    $listArray["HealthAreas"].Add($item["Health_x0020_Area"])
    $listArray["ResourceType"].Add($item["Resource_x0020_Type"])
    $listArray["ExternalURL"].Add($item["External_x0020_file_x0020_path"])
    $listArray["Active"].Add($item["Currently_x0020_active_x003f_"])
}

Write-Host "############################"
Write-Host $listArray | ConvertTo-Json
```

I know there's a gap in my thinking here (maybe I need a hashtable) but just can't see it. The error I'm receiving is:

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

However I can't see where my null variable may be originating from as I've confirmed each item in the loop does contain data (by writing to console).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you receive is not related to SharePoint but to PowerShell. You created the PowerShell array and tried to access its elements like it was associative array/hashtable.

Please try this code (I've tested it with my own list with different column names and it works fine):

```
#Lookup Source Address 
$rootWeb = $Context.Web
$List = $rootWeb.lists.getByTitle($ListName)
$fields = $List.Fields;
$ListItems = $List.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())

#Load the List
$Context.Load($rootWeb)
$Context.Load($List)
$Context.Load($ListItems)
$context.Load($fields)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

$listArray = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

Write-Host "List items are"
foreach ($item in $ListItems)
{
    $listArray.Add([hashtable]@{
        DisplayTitle=$item["Title"]; 
        Description= $item["File Description"]; 
        Setting= $item["Setting"]; 
        HealthAreas= $item["Health_x0020_Area"]; 
        ResourceType= $item["Resource_x0020_Type"]; 
        ExternalURL= $item["External_x0020_file_x0020_path"]; 
        Active= $item["Currently_x0020_active_x003f_"];     
        }
    )       
}

Write-Host "############################"
$json = $listArray | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Host $json
```